# NSUTF8StringEncoding causes file to render improperly in TextEdit/Pages, but not BBEdit/vi

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, encoding, nsstring, uitextview

I'm running into a bit of a weird issue.  Whenever I create a new text file in my iOS application, I set its encoding to be `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.  If I edit the file and input any characters with diacritics and save the changes, the diacritics render properly in some applications such as BBEdit, TextMate, cat and vi but not in others such as TextEdit, Quick Look and Pages.

I'm using the following code to save the contents of a UITextView to the plain txt files.

```
  NSError *error;
  NSString *dataString = self.textView.text;
  BOOL savedChanges = [dataString writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8Encoding error:&error]; 
  if (!savedChanges)
  {
    // Pop up an alert saying something went wrong.
  }
```

[image: What happens after saving my file. Should say I Love It with some weird diacritics]

The unix `file` command reports that the saved file is indeed "UTF-8 Unicode text, with no line terminators"

What's even weirder is if I save the file again without changing the contents of the text, the file will then render properly in Quick Look & TextEdit on my Mac.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` method should automatically set the `com.apple.TextEncoding` attribute on the file correctly, which should be sufficient for Quicklook and TextEdit. I don't reproduce your issue. Perhaps whatever was causing your issue has been fixed since you ran into it in 2010.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but could it have something to do with a lack of a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? For UTF8, the BOM looks like `EF BB BF` in hex, and should be the very first thing in the file.

Comment: The BOM is not needed for UTF-8 (as its byte ordering is consistent regardless of endianness), and should generally be avoided as a lot of apps don't properly deal with a UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: However, after a quick test, putting the BOM in *does* cause QuickLook and TextEdit to interpret it correctly in this case. Possibly the file is too short for the OS to identify it with certainty as UTF-8. It's certainly treating it as MacRoman.

Answer (score 1):

If you save a text file with an UTF BOM, and the `com.apple.TextEncoding` xattr is not set, any software that opens it will have to guess at the correct character encoding. Some apps guess UTF-8, some guess Mac OS Roman, and others guess something else.

You can replicate this behavior by saving a file as UTF-8 with no BOM, and then in Terminal give the `xattr -d com.apple.TextEncoding filename.txt` command.

To set the xattr, you would call setxattr(). There doesn't seem to be a documented way to set it via a Cocoa API. You could also prefix your data with the UTF-8 BOM.

There's the question of what character encoding should be assumed when the BOM and xattr are missing. Is it a bug if it defaults to Mac OS Roman? Should UTF-8 be the default?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative if you want to avoid the BOM is to set the `com.apple.TextEncoding` extended attribute to `UTF-8;134217984` on the file -- [See here for more details](http://vnoel.wordpress.com/2008/06/18/weird-utf-8-bug-in-quicklook-its-the-ea/).

I don't know how you would do that from code, but `xattr -w com.apple.TextEncoding 'UTF-8;134217984' filename.txt` will do it at the command line to confirm that it fixes the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue just yesterday! [My problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539709/problem-creating-utf8-text-file-with-nsfilehandle) was that files created with by `NSString` `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` were being read and interpreted by QuickLook and Text Edit perfectly, but files created by writing UTF-8 data straight to a file with `NSFileHandle` did not work in QL & TE (the automatic encoding got it wrong).

[Peter Hosey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30461/peter-hosey) pointed me to this question and after some testing it turns out that the `NSString` method does not use the BOM, instead it just uses the extended attribute `com.apple.TextEncoding`. With some code I found online I created an `NSString` category to allow you to set this value easily by passing a file path and a `NSStringEncoding` value.

[NSString (FileTextEncodingAttribute) on gist.github](http://gist.github.com/543667)

An example would be:

```
[NSString setTextEncodingAttribute:NSUTF8StringEncoding atPath:@"myfile.txt"];
```

I've tested this and it works perfectly :) Who knew writing a plain text file would take so much research!!